# Area of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$ limited by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=6y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have

$$\sqrt{1+\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg)^2}=\frac{6}{\sqrt{36-x^2-y^2}}$$

where $z=\sqrt{36-x^2-y^2}$

In the polar form I have to solve

$$\frac{\sigma}{2}= \int_0^\pi \int_0^{6\sin \theta} \frac{6}{\sqrt{36-\rho^2}}\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta=\int_0^\pi\bigg[-6\sqrt{36-\rho^2}\bigg]_0^{6\sin \theta}\,d\theta=\bigg[36\theta -36\sin \theta\bigg]_0^\pi=^?36\pi$$

If I solve this way

$$\frac{\sigma}{4}= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{6\sin \theta} \frac{6}{\sqrt{36-\rho^2}}\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta=18\pi-36$$

It gives me the real answer $\sigma=72\pi-144$

Why this happens?

Comment: I put $=^?$ because WolframAlpha gives the real answer to the same double integral

Comment: I'm confused...is the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 6$ or $x^2 + y^2 = 6y$. If it's the latter, then I don't see how your inner integral has the correct bounds. (It might well have the correct bounds...I just don't see it!)

Comment: I have a mistake, I'll fix immediately

Answer (score 4):

You simplified a square root incorrectly. When you substitute the limits $\rho=0$ and $\rho=6\sin\theta$ to the function $\sqrt{36-\rho^2}$ at the upper limit you get
$$
\sqrt{36-36\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{36\cos^2\theta}=6|\cos \theta|.
$$

It seems to me that you forgot to take the absolute value. Because $\cos\theta$ is negative in the interval $\theta\in(\pi/2,\pi]$ this makes a difference.

With the absolute value in place you are more or less forced to do the subintervals $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $\theta\in[\pi/2,\pi]$ separately leading to your other solution.

Comment: How I can know when I have to put the absolute value?  thanks very much your answer, it is very useful.

Comment: @MauricioJ.S. The rule that is always valid reads $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$ Whether you can drop the absolute value sign depends on whether $x$ can be negative. Here it can.